# Bit array in an Oracle column

Tags: oracle, bitarray

I have a number of sources for information that I need to store in a table (along with other information). As of now I don't know which and how many sources there will be. The source is not required by business logic but rather is stored only for investigative purposes only. Also, this table will be used in production only once for data migration, so I would like to keep the solution as simple as possible (i.e. not do a properly normalized table structure).

I could create a boolean column for each source (as in `source1 char(1) default '0', source2 char(1) default '0'` etc.) However, I would have to add a column for each new source. What I'd like to have is a column that's a bit array, each bit representing one source. This is very similar to the order_status column mentioned in the [documentation for the BITAND function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions022.htm#SQLRF00612).

My question is,

1. What would be the preferred data type for this column assuming that there will be say max. 16 sources? NUMBER(2)?
2. How would I update this field (e.g. set bit number 3)? I've been looking into UTL_RAW functions but they all seem to (surprise, surprise) expect RAW input which makes things a little cumbersome.

I'm open to other ideas as well, as long adding a new source doesn't require changes in the table structure. (I'm aware that using bit arrays in a database table is rarely a good idea, but these are special circumstances so no need to comment on that.) Our DB is 12c (12.1).

Answer (score 3):

Create an Object Type:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE bitarray AS OBJECT(
  data   BLOB,
  len    NUMBER(38,0),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bitarray( in_length NUMBER ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bitarray( in_data VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
  MEMBER FUNCTION getBit( in_index NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION setBit( in_index NUMBER, in_value NUMBER ) RETURN bitarray,
  MEMBER FUNCTION toString RETURN CLOB,
  STATIC FUNCTION byteToRaw( in_value BINARY_INTEGER ) RETURN RAW
);
/

CREATE TYPE BODY bitarray AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bitarray( in_length NUMBER ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
    p_raw RAW(1) := BITARRAY.BYTETORAW( 0 );
  BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( SELF.DATA, FALSE );
    SELF.LEN  := in_length;
    FOR i IN 1 .. CEIL( in_length / 8 ) LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( SELF.DATA, 1, p_raw );
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION bitarray( in_data VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
    p_value  BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    p_power  BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
  BEGIN
    SELF.LEN  := LENGTH( in_data );
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( SELF.DATA, FALSE );
    FOR i IN 1 .. SELF.LEN LOOP
      IF SUBSTR( in_data, i, 1 ) = '1' THEN
        p_value := p_value + p_power;
      END IF;
      IF MOD( i, 8 ) = 0 OR i = SELF.LEN THEN
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( SELF.DATA, 1, BITARRAY.BYTETORAW( p_value ) );
        p_value := 0;
        p_power := 1;
      ELSE
        p_power := p_power * 2;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION getBit( in_index NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    p_amount     BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
    p_raw        RAW(1);
    p_bit_index  BINARY_INTEGER := MOD( in_index - 1, 8 );
    p_byte_index BINARY_INTEGER := ( in_index - 1 - p_bit_index ) / 8 + 1;
    p_bit_value  BINARY_INTEGER := POWER( 2, p_bit_index );
  BEGIN
    IF in_index IS NULL OR in_index < 1 OR in_index > SELF.LEN THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    DBMS_LOB.READ( SELF.DATA, p_amount, p_byte_index, p_raw );
    RETURN BITAND( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_BINARY_INTEGER( p_raw ), p_bit_value ) / p_bit_value;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION setBit( in_index NUMBER, in_value NUMBER ) RETURN bitarray
  AS
    p_amount     BINARY_INTEGER := 1;
    p_raw        RAW(1);
    p_bit_index  BINARY_INTEGER := MOD( in_index - 1, 8 );
    p_byte_index BINARY_INTEGER := ( in_index - 1 - p_bit_index ) / 8 + 1;
    p_bit_value  RAW(1)         := BITARRAY.BYTETORAW( POWER( 2, p_bit_index ) );
    p_array      bitarray       := SELF;
  BEGIN
    IF in_index IS NULL OR in_value NOT IN ( 0, 1 ) OR in_index < 1 OR in_index > SELF.LEN THEN
      RETURN p_array;
    END IF;
    DBMS_LOB.READ( SELF.DATA, p_amount, p_byte_index, p_raw );
    IF in_value = 1 THEN
      p_raw := UTL_RAW.BIT_OR( p_raw, p_bit_value );
    ELSE
      p_raw := UTL_RAW.BIT_AND( p_raw, UTL_RAW.BIT_COMPLEMENT( p_bit_value ) );
    END IF;
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE( p_array.DATA, p_amount, p_byte_index, p_raw );
    RETURN p_array;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION toString RETURN CLOB
  AS
    p_string CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. SELF.LEN LOOP
      IF SELF.getBit(i) = 0 THEN
        p_string := p_string || '0';
      ELSIF SELF.getBit(i) = 1 THEN
        p_string := p_string || '1';
      ELSE
        p_string := p_string || '-';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN p_string;
  END;

  STATIC FUNCTION byteToRaw( in_value BINARY_INTEGER ) RETURN RAW
  AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN UTL_RAW.SUBSTR( UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER( in_value ), 4, 1 );
  END;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

Then you can use it in SQL:

```
SELECT BITARRAY(5).toString() AS default_value,
       BITARRAY('10110').toString() AS with_values,
       BITARRAY('10110').setBit(3,0).toString() AS set_values
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
DEFAULT_VALUE | WITH_VALUES | SET_VALUES
:------------ | :---------- | :---------
00000         | 10110       | 10010
```

**Storage in a Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT, bits BITARRAY );
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 1, bitarray( 4 ).setBit( 1, 1 ).setBit( 4, 1 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, bitarray( '1011001' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Then query it using:

```
SELECT id, t.bits.toString() FROM table_name t;
```

which outputs:

```
ID | T.BITS.TOSTRING()
-: | :----------------
 1 | 1001             
 1 | 1011001
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1933a648579b43837c5c49233230cff0)*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating such a **column**, how about creating a **table**? It would contain two columns:

- source name
- Boolean info

For example:

```
SQL> create table that_table
  2    (source_name varchar2(30),
  3     cb_bool     number(1) default 0 not null
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into that_table
  2    select 'source 1', 0 from dual union all
  3    select 'source 2', 1 from dual union all
  4    select 'source 9', 1 from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * From that_table;

SOURCE_NAME                       CB_BOOL
------------------------------ ----------
source 1                                0
source 2                                1
source 9                                1

SQL>
```

As opposed to your idea, this *scales* and it doesn't really matter how many sources there are - you'd just `INSERT` a new (or `UPDATE` existing) row.

Comment: Sure, this would be the "normal" design. The problem is I use MERGE statements to populate the table. This would require me to do two separate MERGE statements and run the query for those MERGE statements twice. I was just trying to figure out if I can use subquery refactoring with MERGE. That would probably work.